# Was C. S. Lewis a "muscular" Christian?

Tags: cs-lewis

[Muscular Christianity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscular_Christianity) is a movement, originating in nineteenth-century Britain, associated with promoting physical health, athleticism, and active evangelism.  Many critics say that C. S. Lewis, particularly in his fiction, drew from this tradition:

> ... Lewis's creed of clean-living, muscular Christianity, pipe-smoking, misogyny, racism, and the most vulgar snobbery. (Philip Hensher, *The Independent* column of 4 December 1998)
>
> Not surprisingly, some readers embrace Narnia's pagan flavor in preference to its muscular Christianity. (Naomi Wood, *God in the Details*, in *Revisiting Narnia*, ed. Shanna Caughey, 2005)
>
> ... his polemical, somewhat muscular, orthodox Anglican Christianity ... (Terence Brown, *C. S. Lewis: Irishman?*, chapter in *Ireland's literature*, 1988)

Did Lewis have anything to say about "muscular Christianity" as an idea, and did he associate himself with the concept? I would certainly count him as a forceful defender of Christian ideas, but not as someone particularly interested in physical fitness.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No.

C.S. Lewis [converted to Christianity in 1931](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._S._Lewis#Conversion_to_Christianity).  While there is no doubt that Muscular Christianity, as a movement, was still around at that time, the largest proponents for muscular Christianity, [Charles Kingsley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Kingsley) and [Thomas Hughes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hughes), died before 1900.

This, of course, does not preclude C.S. Lewis from adhering to these views.  However, [his corpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliography_of_C._S._Lewis) does not include any significant writings regarding Muscular Christianity.

We can presume that even if he held these beliefs (as your quotes suggest), he was not a vehement supporter of this movement, due to his lack of writing on the subject.

Comment: I suspected the critics were using the term somewhat loosely - probably based on a surface impression of the Narnia books being "good clean fun" for healthy, well-behaved, self-reliant English children. Thank you for confirming his lack of actual ideology on the subject.

Comment: @JamesT My personal opinion/stereotype says that since he was a scholar and a pipe smoker, he probably wasn't hugely into athletics.  Also, everything I've read seems to indicate he's more of an intellectual rather than a physical type of guy.  Finally, does [this look like a guy heavily involved in athletics?](http://classicalworld.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/cs-lewis2.jpg).  Again, these are *pure stereotypes and opinions*.  But still...